# Atom and Boostrap 4 failed to load snippet: "Duplicate key 'Button group - Bootstrap 4'"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment, atom-editor

So I've just installed atom on my desktop and I intend on using Boostrap. I wasn't getting the auto completions/suggestions when using the bootstrap classes, so I did some searching and found this: https://atom.io/packages/atom-bootstrap4.
I went to the `.atom` directory opened `cmd` and pasted

```
apm install atom-bootstrap4
```

It said everything installed correctly so I closed the cmd and restarted Atom.

On loading, I get the following error:
[image: failed to load snippet]
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I found this solution [here](https://github.com/degouville/atom-bootstrap4/issues/25):

I changed
C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\atom-bootstrap4\snippets\components-button_group.cson
line 63

```
'Button group - Bootstrap 4' => 'Button group vertical - Bootstrap 4'
```

C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\atom-bootstrap4\snippets\components-pagination.cson
line 58

```
'Pagination - Bootstrap 4' => 'Pagination small - Bootstrap 4'
```

C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\atom-bootstrap4\snippets\components-cards.cson

```
line 348 ~ 359 deleted
```

C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\atom-bootstrap4\snippets\components-modals.cson
line 6

```
'Modal - Bootstrap 4' => 'Modal button - Bootstrap 4'
```

line 132

```
'Modal content based- Bootstrap 4' => 'Modal content based - Bootstrap 4'
```

(Check the space)

C:\Users\username\.atom\packages\atom-bootstrap4\snippets\components-progress.cson
line 22

```
'Progress - Bootstrap 4' => 'Progress striped animate - Bootstrap 4'
```

Comment: Thank you. Great tutorial. It solved my problem. @Legna